# How do I sort data when printing?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program that you can keep adding items into. But how/where do I put the .sort or .sort() for when I hit Option 5 (Print inventory report) it displays the information by ID number.

For example is I have ID numbers: 1, 4, 2, 3, 10 . When it print the report its 1,2,3,4,10.

I will attach the full program as I don't know when sorting should occur.

Full code:

```
import os
import json

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        #AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.items = {}
        self.load()

    def remove(self, ID):
        #REMOVING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        del self.items[str(ID)]
        self.save()

    def add(self, ID, name, qty):
        #ADDING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[str(ID)] = {"name": name, "qty": qty}
        self.save()

    def update(self, ID, update):
        #UPDATING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[str(ID)]["qty"] += update
        self.save()

    def search(self, query):
        #SEARCHING DATA BASED ON CLOSEST CHARACTER MATCH - NOT CASE SENSITIVE
        for id in self.items:
            if str(query) == id or self.items[id]['name'].lower().startswith(str(query).lower()):
                return id, self.items[id]['name'], self.items[id]['qty']
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        #FORMATTING
        out = ""
        for id, d in self.items.items():
            out += f"ID Number : {id} \nItem Name : {d['name']}\nQuantity : {d['qty']}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out
    
    def save(self):
        #WHERE TO SAVE TO
        with open('data.txt','w') as outfile:
           json.dump(self.items, outfile)

    def load(self):
        #WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM WHEN RELAUNCHING PROGRAM
        try:
            with open('data.txt','r') as json_file:
               self.items = json.load(json_file)
        except:
            print("Can't load old inventory, starting fresh")
            self.items = {}


def menuDisplay():
    #MENU FOR PROGRAM 
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    #ADDING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_ID = int(input("Enter an ID number for the item: "))
            if inventory.search(new_ID):
                print("ID number is taken, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_ID, new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    #REMOVING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    while True:
        try:
            removing = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to remove from inventory: "))
            if inventory.search(removing):
                inventory.remove(removing)
            else:
                print("Item not in inventory")
                continue
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    #OPTION TO CONTINUE OR QUITE PROGRAM
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    #UPDATING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    while True:
        try:
            ID = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to update: "))
            if inventory.search(ID):
                update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
                inventory.update(ID, update)
            else:
                print("ID number is not in the system, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()

def search_inventory(inventory):
    #SEARCHING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    while True:
        try:
            search = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
            result = inventory.search(search)
            if result is None:
                print("Item not in inventory")
                continue
            else:
                ID, name, qty = result
                print('ID Number: ', ID)
                print('Item:     ', name)
                print('Quantity: ', qty)
                print('----------')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def print_inventory(inventory):
    #PRINT CURRENT LIST OF ITEMS IN INVENTORY
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    print(inventory)


def main():
    #PROGRAM RUNNING COMMAND AND ERROR CHECKING
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

Comment: You should consider reducing the code in your question to the specific thing you are having trouble with. I don't think we need 200 lines of code to help with a sort.

Comment: I don't know if sort should go on the add item function or on the dictionary, or before printing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code as a a hot fix But should consider changing your data structure from `dict` which is unordered to something like a 2D array which can be sorted easily the below code take advantage of `__str__` method and use it's fixed output and fact that different items will first differ in their `ID` number to sort it. To see difference in code look at `__str__` (notice /n/r delimiter at end) then look at `print_inventory` function to see how I took advantage of this fact.

```
import os
import json


class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        # AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.items = {}
        self.load()

    def remove(self, ID):
        # REMOVING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        del self.items[str(ID)]
        self.save()

    def add(self, ID, name, qty):
        # ADDING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[str(ID)] = {"name": name, "qty": qty}
        self.save()

    def update(self, ID, update):
        # UPDATING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[str(ID)]["qty"] += update
        self.save()

    def search(self, query):
        # SEARCHING DATA BASED ON CLOSEST CHARACTER MATCH - NOT CASE SENSITIVE
        for id in self.items:
            if str(query) == id or self.items[id]['name'].lower().startswith(str(query).lower()):
                return id, self.items[id]['name'], self.items[id]['qty']
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        # FORMATTING
        out = ""
        for id, d in self.items.items():
            out += f"\nID Number : {id} \nItem Name : {d['name']}\nQuantity : {d['qty']}\n"
            out += "----------\n\r"
        return out

    def save(self):
        # WHERE TO SAVE TO
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self.items, outfile)

    def load(self):
        # WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM WHEN RELAUNCHING PROGRAM
        try:
            with open('data.txt', 'r') as json_file:
                self.items = json.load(json_file)
        except:
            print("Can't load old inventory, starting fresh")
            self.items = {}


def menuDisplay():
    # MENU FOR PROGRAM
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    # ADDING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_ID = int(input("Enter an ID number for the item: "))
            if inventory.search(new_ID):
                print("ID number is taken, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_ID, new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    # REMOVING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    while True:
        try:
            removing = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to remove from inventory: "))
            if inventory.search(removing):
                inventory.remove(removing)
            else:
                print("Item not in inventory")
                continue
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    # OPTION TO CONTINUE OR QUITE PROGRAM
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    # UPDATING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    while True:
        try:
            ID = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to update: "))
            if inventory.search(ID):
                update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
                inventory.update(ID, update)
            else:
                print("ID number is not in the system, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def search_inventory(inventory):
    # def select(obj: object):
    #     return o

    # SEARCHING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    while True:
        try:
            search = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
            result = inventory.search(search)
            if result is None:
                print("Item not in inventory")
                continue
            else:
                ID, name, qty = result
                print('ID Number: ', ID)
                print('Item:     ', name)
                print('Quantity: ', qty)
                print('----------')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def print_inventory(inventory: object):
    # PRINT CURRENT LIST OF ITEMS IN INVENTORY
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    string = inventory.__str__()
    lis = string.split("\n\r")
    lis.sort()
    print("".join(lis))


def main():
    # PROGRAM RUNNING COMMAND AND ERROR CHECKING
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!" + str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

Comment: Thank you for this update, I will apply your changes and learn from your example.

Answer (score 0):

You have left a comment with a question that I believe will answer also your main question.

*I don't know if sort should go on the add item function or on the dictionary, or before printing the data*

**Answer:**

You should create a sorting function and use it on your dictionary right before printing.

**What not to do:**

Don't sort your array on every added element. It's not efficient and in bigger projects it would cause time loss.

*Disclaimer:*
Sometimes you have to code a program in a way it sorts array on every added element - if you have to do it, then it's fine - but don't do it when it's not needed as sorting is a resource consuming operation